# Does renaming S3 files in spark load the files into memory

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, hadoop2

I am asking this question because my renaming of `S3` files that I generate using `spark` is slower .
I am saving my output file in `spark` like below

```
val dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull = dfMainOutputFinal.withColumnRenamed("concatenated", headerFinal)



dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull.repartition(1).write.partitionBy("DataPartition")
      .format("csv")
      .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss ZZ")
      .option("nullValue", "")
      .option("delimiter", "\t")
      .option("quote", "\u0000")
      .option("header", "true")
      .save(outputFileURL)
```

After saving i need to rename the files which is saved in `S3` .
This is how  am doing this .

```
val file = fs.globStatus(new Path(outputFileURL + "/*/*"))
        val finalPrefix = "Fundamental.Fundamental.Fundamental."
        val fileVersion = "1."
        val formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-hhmm")
        val now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime
        val finalFormat = formatDate.format(now)
        val currentTime = finalFormat + "."

        val fileExtention = "Full.txt"

        for (urlStatus <- file) {
          val DataPartitionName = urlStatus.getPath.toString.split("=")(1).split("\\/")(0).toString

          val finalFileName = finalPrefix + DataPartitionName + "." + fileVersion + currentTime + fileExtention
          val dest = new Path(mainFileURL + "/" + finalFileName)
          fs.rename(urlStatus.getPath, dest)
        }
        println("File renamed and moved to dir now delete output folder")
        myUtil.Utility.DeleteOuptuFolder(fs, outputFileURL)
```

This renaming of the files takes more than 15 minutes .
I have approx 2k files of total size 200GB  .
Am i doing something wrong here ?

Is there any better way to this ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a copy in the AWS S3 store, which is generally measured at 6-10MB/s.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of over naming in S3. I would recommend persist to hdfs and then do s3-distcp which is fater.